# Driver error when trying to install Steam on 16.10

Tags: drivers, software-installation, steam, 16.10

I downloaded the Steam `.deb` file from the official website, but after installing it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
```

I have found that upon trying to launch it with:

```
steam
```

I now get this error:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/<username>/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
awk: /home/<username>/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1476379980)
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Initially it asked me to just install some dependencies (the drivers it is complaining about now I guess) and it installed Steam with the usual window and everything but then told me that there as a fatal error and that it had to close. This was because I didn't install the dependencies as it launched an untrusted window asking for my password, however after the installation of Steam I did install the dependencies it requested.

However now it just gives me the error above, I have tried purging it and reinstalling it many times but now it doesn't even try to download Steam in the usual way with the little Steam window, now it just gives me that error.

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 with GNOME 3.22, what do I do to fix the problem and be able to install and launch Steam successfully?

Also, I would prefer to install it from the official source rather than from the universe repository as I don't know how well this is maintained.

Comment: maybe you updated??

Comment: Try searching past questions for "steam i965" or "steam swrast" or "steam libgl error". I think you'll find your question has been asked (and answered) dozens of times on this site

Comment: @NickWeinberg: If you can find an answer which answers my question and a question which asks what I ask, then please flag/VTC this as a duplicate. My search functionality over here is very slow.

Comment: Maybe you could try to use this source? I don't know if its an official source maintained by Valve, but it seems to be updated rather frequently: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/steam

Comment: @Promille: I'm not sure I trust it if it's just some third-party PPA, they could put anything there.

Comment: @AndyBalaam: Please don't flag questions as duplicates of questions that are closed as a duplicate themselves. Instead, follow the thread of duplicates until you find one that is no duplicate.

Comment: @DavidFoerster: Although it may be preferable to do this for the sake of ease of finding the originating question, this is by no means an enforced requirement it should be noted.